# Boolean always returns whatever value I assign when initialised, but it doesn't check the conditional statement

Tags: java, methods, conditional-statements

I spent two hours trying to find out why the boolean expression always returns whatever value is assigned from the beginning instead of taking the value from the correct conditional statement. 
In this case, the `boolean question` from the `questionOneAnswer()` method returns true even if my input is `A` or `C` or `D`, which means the score is added even if the answer is wrong. 
However, if I assign `boolean question` to false in `questionOneAnswer()` and my input is `B` (which is the correct answer) the code in `score()` method `qOneCheck` is not executed, therefore, score stays at 0.

```
      import java.util.Scanner;     
      import java.util.Random;
      class miniProject
      {
         public static void main(String[] args)
         {

             questionOne(); 
             questionOneAnswer();
             int scr = score();

             System.out.println("Your score is " + scr);



             System.exit(0); 
          }


            /* *********************************
            This method asks for a question and gives 4 possible answers
            */ 
            public static void questionOne()
            {
               System.out.println("Please, type the letter which you think 
               contain the right answer!");
               System.out.println("  ");
               System.out.println("How many oscars did the Titanic movie 
               got?");
               System.out.println("A. 12    B.11    C.3    D.32");

               return; // Ends the method 

            }
           public static int score()
           {    
              boolean qOneCheck = questionOneAnswer();
              int currentScore = 0;
              int oldScore = 0;
              int newScore = 0;
              int random = randomGen();


             if(qOneCheck == true)
          {
             currentScore = currentScore + random;
             newScore = currentScore;

          }
          else 
          {
            currentScore = oldScore;
          }     



            return newScore;
          }   



        public static  boolean questionOneAnswer()
        {
             boolean question = true;
             String i = input();


             if (i.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
             {
                 System.out.println("False, you don't get any points!");
                 question = false;
             }

             else if (i.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
             {
               System.out.println("You answer is correct");

              question = true;
             }

             if (i.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
             {
              System.out.println("False, you don't get any points!");
                  question = false;
             }

            if (i.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
            {
                  System.out.println("False, you don't get any points!");
                question = false;
            }



            return question;//Ends method 
         }

          /* *********************************
          This method receives input from user and stors it in String 
             called answer
          */ 
          public static String input()
          {      
               Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
               String answer;
               answer = scanner.nextLine();

              return answer; // returns String answer when method is 
             called 

            }



         public static int randomGen()
         {
              Random score = new Random();

              int score1 = score.nextInt(10) +1;



               return score1;   


           }


        }
```

EDIT: After removing `questioOneAnswer()` I finally got the result. Thanks to all of you guys. I finally gona go to sleep now hah.

Comment: Please share the source of the `input()` method.

Comment: Does the text in the `println` ("False, ...", "Your answer is correct") appear?

Comment: I don't know what other user will say but for me is running as expected, and method `questionOneAnswer` is returning true or false accordingly. Are you using an IDE? Did you recompile?

Comment: Yes, it does. However, points are being added or not depending on the boolean assignment (true or false).

Comment: I am compiling it through CMD. Saving, recompiling again and again and the result is always the same ...

Comment: The code works fine. Returns `true` for `a` and `false` for the rest. provide some details, how exactly you call it

Comment: The call order in `main` seems a bit chaotic: First you call `score()` which in turn calls `questionOneAnswer()` to process the answer. Then you call `questionOne()` which shows the question, I guess. Finally you call `questionOneAnswer()` again but without looking at the result.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelButscher. I would suggest you to remove `questionOne()` and `questionOneAnswer()` from the `main` method and compile and run again so you can check the rest works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well among other things your code has this problem:

[image]

I commented out the bits we didn't have yet, and it worked:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int scr = score();
//      questionOne();
//      questionOneAnswer();
    System.out.println("Your score is " + scr);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I dunno why you're calling questionOneAnswer(); a second time (once inside score - where you assign the value to a temporary variable) and once again in the main where you don't even assign the boolean returned to anything.

```
public static int score() {
    boolean qOneCheck = questionOneAnswer();
    int currentScore = 0;
    int oldScore = 0;
    int newScore = 0;
//      int random = randomGen();
    if (qOneCheck == true) {
//          currentScore = currentScore + random;
        currentScore = currentScore + 1;
        newScore = currentScore;
    } else {
        currentScore = oldScore;
        newScore = currentScore;
    }
    return newScore;
}
```

Most of this is garbage.  Each time you call score() current, old and new are all set to 0.

Something like:

```
static int runningTotal = 0;

public static int score() {
    if (questionOneAnswer()) runningTotal++;
}
```

Or kill two birds with one stone:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    score();
    System.out.println("Your score is " + scr);
    System.exit(0);
}

static int scr = 0;

public static int score() {
    if (questionOneAnswer()) scr++;
}
```

Also the default in questionOneAnswer(); shouldn't be true, it should be false, then you can fix the problem I led out with (bogus input will be false).  But even more than that we can boil the method down too:

```
public static boolean questionOneAnswer() {
    String i = input();
    return i.equalsIgnoreCase("B");
}
```

I didn't look at the input method.

TLDR: commenting out the two superfluous lines in the main method and whatever it was that randomgen thinks it's doing seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Well, basically I deleted only the `questionOneAnswer()` as the `questionOne` needs to print the question and now all seems to works fine. This is a big project for uni which is separated in 10 levels and at the moment I don't need to worry about other inputs like `E`,  but thanks for mentioning it, I will have it in mind. Also, I am not allowed to use global variables. I will see and fix `score()` as I don't want to initialize the values to `0` every time when called. Thanks again, much appreciated!!!

Comment: Yeah global variables are bad.  One way around that might be to make them instance variables and then pull the contents of your current main method into a 'doStuff' method, and then all the main needs to do is to make an instance of the class containing doStuff, and invoke doStuff on that instance.  Et viola!  Suddenly all the statics can go away (except for static on the main method of course) - since everything is now on the instance of the class, rather than on the instance of the Class (which is where statics/globals hide).

Comment: Well, what about If I do 1 method to store only the score accumulated during the whole game as there will be more questions? Or is it bad practice if I just do another method to deal with the score for each question. For instance, let say now for question 2 just returning the value from question one(whether is 0 or randomGen)  score to question two score method and carrying on to the last question with creating more methods for the score?

Comment: Any variables that you declare within the method are scoped for that method, and will be reset each time the method is called.